# Mockito.verify doesn't work with Lombok @Delegate

Tags: java, testing, junit, mockito, lombok

So I experience the following behaviour when trying to verify calls on mock (same for spy) which uses Lombok @Delegate inside:

```
public class SomeClass {

    @Delegate
    private final Map<String, String> map;
...
}
```

Test:

```
@Mock //same for @Spy ..
private SomeClass someClassMock;

@Test
void someTest() {
    ...
    verify(someClassMock, times(0)).put(anyString(), anyString()); // <-- NullPointerException
}
```

Looks like Mockito doesn't understand that "put" method comes from the underlying delegated class.
Any ideas how to make it work?

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you are initializing the mock, via [`initMocks()`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.28/org/mockito/MockitoAnnotations.html#initMocks(java.lang.Object)) or [`MockitoJUnitRunner`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.6.8/org/mockito/junit/MockitoJUnitRunner.html) (or [`MockitoExtension`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-junit-jupiter/3.2.4/org/mockito/junit/jupiter/MockitoExtension.html) if you are using JUnit5

The below works perfectly,

```
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.anyString;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.mockito.internal.verification.VerificationModeFactory.times;

import java.util.Map;

import lombok.experimental.Delegate;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class DelTest {

    class TestMap<K, V> {

       @Delegate
       Map<K, V> map;
   }

   @Mock//same for @Spy ..
   private TestMap<String, String> someClassMock;

   @Test
   void someTest() {
       when(someClassMock.put(anyString(),anyString())).thenReturn("x");
       someClassMock.put("a","b");
       verify(someClassMock, times(1)).put(anyString(), anyString());
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I do initialize with initMocks(), also - thinkg like when() work ok with the Delegate. I will try to check again what am I missing

Answer (score 2):

There was no issue with that, I used verify() incorrectly.

I've used

```
verify(someClassMock, times(0)).put(any(), any(), any());
```

instead of

```
verify(someClassMock, times(0)).put(any(), any(), anyLong());
```

(my actual SomeClass doesn't use Map but uses some class that exposes void 
`put(K key, V value, long ttl)`)